# Application.cfc built-in variables

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, application.cfc

In ColdFusion version 9, I have the following in Index.cfm:

```
<cfdump var="#Application#">
```

But the only thing I'm getting back is a struct with the applicationname - no other variables like rootPath, mappings or customTagPath.

Here's what I have in Application.cfc:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
<cfset this.name = left("App_#hash(getCurrentTemplatePath())#",64)>
<cfset this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,8,0,0)>
<cfset this.sessionManagement=True>
<cfset this.loginStorage = "session">
<cfset this.clientManagement = False>
<cfset this.setClientCookies = True>
<cfset this.setDomainCookies = False>
<cfset this.scriptProtect = "all">
<cfset this.rootPath = getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath())>
<cfset this.mappings = this.rootPath>
<cfset this.customTagPaths = "#this.rootPath#Components">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because those settings aren't in the Application Scope. You are confusing Application *settings* versus Application values. If you want them available in the Application scope, you can simply set them up in your onApplicationStart(). You can also see them via the This scope of course, so you copy the values there.

Comment: As an example, you can do this:

<cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returnType="boolean" output="false">
 <cfset application.customtagpaths = this.customtagpaths>
 <cfreturn true>
</cffunction>

In this case I just copied the custom tag path.

Comment: So you're saying that 'this.foo' is an application value, and 'application.bar' is an application setting? I assume that the application settings are all defined somewhere and the values are whatever you'd like?

Comment: No - this.foo would be an application setting, IF it were valid. To set an application _variable_, you use the application scope. And yep, the Application settings are listed here:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-750b.html